# Counting how many times each element appeared in the "search"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, count

Please have a look at the below query

```
SELECT `indexVal` FROM `key_word`WHERE `hashed_word` IN ('001','01v','0ji','0k9','0vc','0@v','0%d','13#' ,'148' ,'1e1','1sx','1v$','1@c','1?b','1?k','226','2kl','2ue','2*l','2?4','36h','3au','3us','4d~')
```

This will select the list of `indexVal`. A small screenshot of the result is below.

[image]

But this is not what I need. I need to know "how many times" each  `indexVal` appeared in the "search". For an example, something like

```
[1,400] [30,30000] [5555,78789]
```

In above, imagine each single bracket represents a row in table. The first Items is the first row, which represents the `indexVal`. The second item is the second column, which represents how many number of times the `indexVal` appeared in search.

My SQL knowledge is not good, now started reading stuff. So, how can I do this? I appreciate your advice.

**I need to know how many times each item appear in "search", not in "table"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select indexval,count(indexval) from key_word where hashed_word IN ('001','01v','0ji','0k9','0vc','0@v','0%d','13#' ,'148' ,'1e1','1sx','1v$','1@c','1?b','1?k','226','2kl','2ue','2*l','2?4','36h','3au','3us','4d~')    group by indexval
```

Comment: Hi, you have missed `Hashed words in` stuff

Answer (score 2):

For counting you can use

```
SELECT 
`indexVal`,count(*) as `total` 
FROM `key_word`
where
`hashed_word` IN ('001','01v','0ji','0k9','0vc','0@v','0%d','13#' ,'148' ,'1e1','1sx','1v$','1@c','1?b','1?k','226','2kl','2ue','2*l','2?4','36h','3au','3us','4d~')
group by `indexVal`
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea about how to speed up this? It takes 2 seconds.

Comment: you need to use `EXPLAIN` followed by your query to see whats going on. I presume you are missing index on  hashed_word

Comment: No, this couns how many times the `indexVal` appear in "table". This is not what I need. I need to know many times they appear in "search"